# Store UTF-8 encoding of a String in a ByteString

Tags: haskell, utf-8, bytestring

So I want to access the individual bytes of the UTF-8 encoding of a string.

I tried using [`Data.ByteString.Char8.pack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:pack), but that seems to just truncate it to the last byte of each character:

```
ghci> Char8.pack "\945\946\947" 
"\177\178\179"
```

This isn't a problem if I can read the string from a file:

```
ghci> Prelude.writeFile "temp.txt" "\945\946\947" >> Char8.readFile "temp.txt"
"\206\177\206\178\206\179"
```

But I'd like a pure way to convert `String -> ByteString` without truncation, and [hoogle isn't very helpful](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+ByteString).

Comment: I remembered reading something about hayoo including more packages in its search than hoogle, so I [tried your search there](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html#0:String%20-%3E%20ByteString), and it gave me the right answer as the second result:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Data.ByteString.UTF8.fromString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/utf8-string/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-UTF8.html#v%3afromString):

```
ghci> import Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BSUTF8
ghci> :t BSUTF8.fromString
BSUTF8.fromString :: String -> ByteString
ghci> BSUTF8.fromString "\945\946\947"
"\206\177\206\178\206\179"
```

Alternatively, you can use [`encode{Strict,Lazy}ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/encoding/latest/doc/html/Data-Encoding.html#v%3aencodeStrictByteString) from the [`encoding`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding) package, which offers a lot more encodings than just UTF-8:

```
ghci> import Data.Encoding as E
ghci> import Data.Encoding.UTF8
ghci> E.encodeStrictByteString UTF8 "\945\946\947"
"\206\177\206\178\206\179"
```

Comment: The encoding package is rather nice! I wish it didn't have so many high-level dependencies...